# How to make a function that returns a generic object?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, generics

I am trying to make a function that returns a T/Any object. The only thing is that i am not quite sure how to do it.

```
 fun readMockData(context: Context, filename: String): Any {
    val json = context.assets.open("$filename.json").bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
    return RetrofitSingleton.GSON.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<Any>() {}.type)
}
```

This is what i tried at first, but i am getting an error.
How am i supposed to make this function properly?

Comment: `<T>` and `Any` are not the same thing. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i try to return a generic object that i just can cast to whatever object i need.

Comment: i get a object from this json, turns it to the right object and return it normally. But i make the same function that look so similar so many times, so i wondered if i could make something more generic? if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is what you need:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified T> readMockData(context: Context, filename: String): T {
    val json = context.assets.open("$filename.json").bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
    return RetrofitSingleton.GSON.fromJson(json, typeOf<T>().javaType)
}
```

Note it has to be inline, because otherwise there is no way to acquire a type. If your function is longer than above, it may be a good idea to split it into an inline reified wrapper and the main function that accepts `Type` as a parameter.

It uses reflection, so you need to add a dependency to it. Also, `typeOf()` is experimental, but from my experience it just works (at least on JVM) and it is there for a long time, so I guess it won't change.

Comment: In the meantime I noticed I probably missed `.javaType` in my original answer. I edited it, but please confirm if you needed to add it, so the answer will be the correct one (for future readers). @Meyben